# How to pass input X and y_pred to custom loss function in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to create a custom loss function for keras, which should calculate the loss using the input X of the model(numpy array) and y_pred of the model. I used this:

```
def customloss(x):
    def loss(x,y_pred):
       _img_based_on_pred = make_an_image_with_respect_to(y_pred)
       return distance(x,_img_basedon_pred)
    return loss
```

and pass the parameters like this:

```
_gen.compile(loss=[customloss(inputs)],optimizer='SGD',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Keras will send `inputs` to customloss and also the y_pred but in the `loss` the `make_an_image_respect_to` recives the `y_pred`, it is as a Tensor and i cant read it. The model output must be some float numbers and this is  the thing i need to `make_an_image_respect_to`.

How should i do such a thing? To send both the input sample and the y_pred to a custom loss funtion?

Ps:
I'm making a model to extract some parameters from an image. I wanna send back(the loss) the diffrence(the distance function) between input image and the image made by parameters estimated by the model(using a function).